# Right angled triangle symbol ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology

Does anyone knows if there is a Right angled triangle symbol into ArcMap standard symbology? I've found only isosceles triangles.

Answer (score 7):

You can follow the instruction in the image below, if this is what you have been asking for:

[image]

Also, you can find many in Font ESRI Geometric Symbols (filled symbols and unfilled symbols). you can adjust the angle, size, and color as you like.

[image]